# Is there an alternative method for ignoring type definitions in F# when running code coverage?

Tags: f#

I usually ignore blocks of code by applying the following attribute to classes or properties in C#:

```
[<DebuggerNonUserCode>] // Kludge for Portable Class Library support
```

For example, if I wanted to ignore type definitions when running code coverage, I would apply the attribute like this:

```
open System.Diagnostics

(* Types *)
[<DebuggerNonUserCode>]
type Form = { 
    Name:Name
    Password:Password
}

[<DebuggerNonUserCode>]
type RegisterResponse =
    | RegistrationNA
    | FirstNameRequired
    | LastNameRequired
    | RegistrationSucceeded
```

The problem with this approach is that type definitions with this attribute aren't as readable.

Is there an alternative approach for ignoring blocks of code without having to use attributes when running code coverage?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid such types? Clearly, they are user-defined...

Comment: Running code coverage will report that the default System.object methods for each type defined has not been tested. Example: GetHashCode ()

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: Because, I only want to identify my business logic that did not get executed. A code coverage report that identifies the system.object methods of all my types not being executed obfuscates the details that I care about.

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't even know that code coverage worked with F#. I don't think it did five years ago, so someone must have put in some work to advance the state of affairs. Given that code coverage for C# doesn't report on inherited members, I'd consider it a bug that this happens for F#. Have you considered reporting the issue?

Comment: I can understand that it's annoying with those false positives. Still, it oughtn't be a blocker, since [absolute code coverage percentages are useless](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/11/16/code-coverage-is-a-useless-target-measure) anyway.

Comment: Okay. I'll research how to log a bug against Visual Studio. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: I think this would be a good place to start: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues